# Insert a jump instruction by using llvm pass

Tags: assembly, llvm, llvm-ir

I want to insert a jump instruction into the target program through the pass of LLVM. I know that branchinst can be used to realize the jump of basic blocks in LLVM. But what I want to achieve is a jump of instructions in the same basic block (assuming I know the destination address of the jump). How do I do that? Iineasm? Can you give me an example?

For example, in C I could implement this:

```
// before insert jmp
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 2;
    if(a<b)
    {
        printf("hh\n");
        printf("jump hh\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

result:  hh
         jump hh

// after insert jmp
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 2;
    if(a<b)
    {
        asm("jmp main+0x30;");
        printf("hh\n");
        printf("jump hh\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

result:  jump hh

cmp    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
jge    1185 <main+0x3c>
jmp    1179 <main+0x30>
lea    0xe90(%rip),%rdi        # 2004 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
callq  1050 <puts@plt>
lea    0xe87(%rip),%rdi        # 2007 <_IO_stdin_used+0x7>
callq  1050 <puts@plt>
```

Comment: An unconditional jump within something that was originally a basic block (no branch targets, no jump) will either make an infinite loop or skip some instructions.  Are you sure you want this to happen at run-time, instead of just removing the instructions you want to skip from the basic block?  (I'm assuming you don't want a backwards jump to create an infloop)

Comment: In my work it is true that all instructions need to be saved and cannot be deleted. In the future, I will control where the code needs to be executed by changing the destination address of the jmp to avoid infinite loops and so on.

Comment: You can't jump into the middle of a basic block or jump from the middle of one; countless code around LLVM relies on both of these restrictions. You have to split the basic block into two or more blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the definition of a Basic Block from Wikipedia:

> In compiler construction, a basic block is a straight-line code sequence with no branches in except to the entry and no branches out except at the exit. This restricted form makes a basic block highly amenable to analysis. Compilers usually decompose programs into their basic blocks as a first step in the analysis process.

With a basic block, if you reach the nth instruction in the block, you must have reached the (n-1)th instruction in the block, up to the first instruction. Hence, no branches to instructions in the middle of a basic block, by definition.

@arnt's suggestion is correct: the way to build this in LLVM is to split the basic block. There's an API for this, see the various flavours of "splitBasicBlock" on BasicBlock: https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1BasicBlock.html

Comment: I'd guess it might be possible to hack something up at a very late stage of code-gen for the specific target machine.  The rest of LLVM doesn't have to know about the jump; the querent just seems to want to break the generated code by skipping a few instructions at run-time.  If LLVM knows about it, e.g. by splitting a basic block, it might optimize away the now-dead part which the querent apparently wants to keep.

Comment: If you're OK with miscompiling the code and figuring out the offset yourself then `asm("jmp main+0x30;");` is fine. This is invalid inline asm in both llvm and gcc because control flow is not allowed in inline asm, see the discussion of "asm goto" in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#GotoLabels . If you want LLVM to help you get the offset, you must use a basic block, `blockaddr` already exists. If you want to hack up the assembly after LLVM is done emitting it, there's no need to involve LLVM.

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea why the querent would want this; makes no sense to me.  Hopefully one of our suggestions will fit what they're looking for.  Hacking up the asm text after LLVM emits it is basically equivalent to what I was suggesting, and probably easier than trying to hack up data structures inside LLVM.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, and I have understood the specific content of what you said. Finally, I realized the target I needed through the way of inline assembly instruction "jmp.+x", where x is the offset address of the target byte to jump, of course, this also involves the determination of the offset address of the target byte, because it involves my specific work, it will not be described here. Thank you for your help, which enabled me to have a further understanding of LLVM and basic blocks